# Registar classes em fábrica a partir de vários ficheiros

Tags: python, factory

Tenho uma fábrica com o seguinte código:

```
class ClassFactory:
    registry = {}

    @classmethod
    def register(cls, name):
        def inner_wrapper(wrapped_class):
            if name in cls.registry:
                print(f'Class {name} already exists. Will replace it')
            cls.registry[name] = wrapped_class
            return wrapped_class
    return inner_wrapper

    @classmethod
    def create_type(cls, name):
        exec_class = cls.registry[name]
        type = exec_class()
        return type


@ClassFactory.register('Class 1')
class M1():
    def __init__(self):
       print ("Starting Class 1")


@ClassFactory.register('Class 2')
class M2():
    def __init__(self):
       print("Starting Class 2")
```

Que funciona como esperava sem problemas:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(ClassFactory.registry.keys())
    foo = ClassFactory.create_type("Class 2")
```

Recebo o resultado esperado de `dict_keys(['Class 1', 'Class 2']) Starting Class 2`

O problema é que eu quero isolar as classes M1 e M2 cada uma em seu ficheiro m1.py e m2.py, e possivelmente no futuro adicionar novo ficheiro com a classe M3, etc. Isto sem precisar de lidar de novo com o ficheiro onde está a ClassFactory. Mas se eu simplesmente coloco a classe M2 em m2.py:

```
from test_ import ClassFactory
@MethodFactory.register('Class 2')
class M2():
    def __init__(self):
        print("Starting Class 2")
```

Tenho o resultado `dict_keys(['Class 1'])` pois a classe nunca chega a ser registada

Portanto a minha questão é: como posso garantir que a classe é registada quando colocada num ficheiro diferente daquele onde está localizada a fábrica sem precisar de alterar o ficheiro com a fábrica cada vez que queira adicionar uma classe? Como registar automaticamente?

Obrigado

Answer (score -1):

É só você criar a seguinte estrutura de ficheiros:

- ClassFactory.py #Aqui você escreve a sua factory
- m1.py
- m2.py
- ...  #Nestes ficheiros você cria cada uma das classes que você quer
- main.py #Aqui você vai realizar o import da factory e de cada classe.

Conteúdo de ClassFactory.py

```
class ClassFactory:
    registry = {}

    @classmethod
    def register(cls, name):
        def inner_wrapper(wrapped_class):
            if name in cls.registry:
                print(f'Class {name} already exists. Will replace it')
            cls.registry[name] = wrapped_class
            return wrapped_class
        return inner_wrapper

    @classmethod
    def create_type(cls, name):
        exec_class = cls.registry[name]
        type = exec_class()
        return type
```

Conteúdo de m1.py (similar a m2.py e m3.py):

```
from ClassFactory import ClassFactory

@ClassFactory.register('Class 1')
class M1():
    def __init__(self):
    print ("Starting Class 1")
```

Conteúdo de main.py:

```
# Import da factory E de cada uma das classes
from ClassFactory import ClassFactory
from m1 import M1
from m2 import M2
from m3 import M3


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(ClassFactory.registry.keys())
```

Execute `python main.py` e você vai obter a seguinte saída:

```
dict_keys(['Class 1', 'Class 2', 'Class 3'])
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Mas assim continuo a não ter registo automático, tenho que alterar explicitamente o main.py ao adicionar um m4, por exemplo.